# How do I have two separate TableViews, same data source, different query method? (firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I think I'm starting to go crazy! So for the sake of argument, say I have a list of players, scores, and idk, age, stored in firebase.

```
{
  "players" : {
     "john": {
         "score" : 50
         "age" : 18
            }
     "bob": {
         "score" : 70
         "age" : 17
            }
     "jimmy": {
         "score" : 100
         "age" : 22
            }
      }
 }
```

So on one tableview in one viewcontroller, I want it queried by age, and in another viewcontroller I want the tableview queried by score. When I tried this, it was messing up the query for everything. Very frustrating. I want both table views to pull from the same DS, but different query method. Can't I just copy the table view over, have the same logic for retrieving my data and simply change the query call? Thanks guys

Comment: What about sharing your code of the queries

Comment: Since you are retrieving the same *amount* of data, why don't you load the data into an array and then have an ageArray and a scoreArray derived from the mainArray? A query comes with a lot of overhead so just loading the data through a standard observe call is a lot faster and would additionally have the benefit of hitting Firebase once instead of twice. It also depends on if you are waiting for events or just a one-shot load. Also, you may have a coding error causing the initial issue so post that code!